# What would be the right way to add a maximum of 2 charts into another class View?

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to C++ and still getting a hang of it. I have got a question on which I am currently working on. The below is the question:

Assume a chart has the following attributes.
Position in space and size is specified by its top left coordinate (x1,y1) and its bottom right coordinate (x2,y2). 
Colour of the chart is specified in RGB, with each value between 0 – 255 (e.g. R=255, G=0, B=0 would imply a red chart)

A. Write a class called Chart that represents the above.

B. Write a class called View that can contain a maximum of 2 charts at a time

For the above, I first created a chart class as shown below:

```
    /* A Class that represents chart properties */
class Chart{
private:
uin8_t x1, y1, x2, y2;              \\The cordinates of each chart
uin8_t red, green, blue;           \\The value at the pixel 
const uin8_t xAxis, yAxis;        \\NxN co-ordinate plane

public:
Chart( uin8_t set_xAxis, uin8_t set_yAxis) {                                     
    xAxis = set_xAxis;
    yAxis = set_yAxis;
   }
};

/* A Class that represents the properties of View */
```

After the class declaration of Chart, I am stuck. Though I understand the logic but I have trouble to implement it as described in the questions. For the question **(B)**, **how do I ensure that the View that can contain a maximum of 2 charts at a time?**. I can implement the functions, my only doubt is on how to ensure the above and what would be the best way forward in context to C++. And how will the view class relate to the chart class when the above is done.

Any suggestions, advice and examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming your View class is going to have a method like `AddChart()`, you could have that method refuse to add a new chart (either by returning an error-value of some sort, or by throwing an exception) if the View already contains two charts.

Comment: What's the point of the axes for the chart? The description mentions two coordinates and one colour, no axis. (I expect that for full marks your class should have exactly three members.)

Answer (score 0):

- In the `View` class, have a `std::vector` of `Chart`s.
- Have a function which adds instances of `Chart` to the `vector`
- In this function, before you add a `Chart` instance to the `vector`, check for the size of the vector using the `size()` function which returns the number of elements in the `vector`.
- If the `size()` is 2, then you can throw an exception and handle it appropriately or just return an error and print an appropriate error-message.